# Create all combinations of boolean for a specified n

Tags: python, python-itertools

I want to replicate the cartesian product of [False,True] n times so that the output should be for example with n=3:

```
[(False, False, False),(False, False, True),(False, True, False),
(False, True, True),(True, False, False),(True, False, True),
(True, True, False),(True, True, True)]
```

I found how to do it with:

```
from itertools import product
list(product([False,True],[False,True],[False,True]))
```

But the thing is that I want to do it for bigger n without writing n times the boolean.

Comment: You're looking for the `repeat` flag.  Try `list(product([False, True], repeat=3))`

Comment: I just want to point out that this is equivalent to counting to 8. You can just look at bits then.

Comment: `def get_bits(n, k): return [bool(n >> i & 1) for i in range(k)];
for x in range(8): print(get_bits(x, 3))`